# Develop lock screen with password in android

Tags: android, android-studio, passwords, locking, lockscreen

**I want to develop an android application to lock the screen with time password.**

How can i start?

**App idea:** The app check the time first and set the time password.

***Example:***

> If the time now is 04:18 then the password should be 0418 and so on.

So.. i don't know how can i start, i deeply searched on the internet and i don't found any tutorials about this.

Hope finding help here :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Get the current time using:**

`Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
  int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);`

**2. Set that as the password.**

Comment: Thank you and i appreciate your time, but i don't know how can i develop lock screen same as in android OS.
i wanna lock screen with same home screen's background and get notifications on it and digital clock on the top and so on.....

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24971524/set-app-background-to-be-the-same-as-home-screen-wallpaper